# How to downsample a PCM audio file on Android

Tags: android, sample, android-mediacodec, rate

I want to generate 8kHz 16 bit PCM from Android Text To Speech.

Android's TTS synthesizeToFile generates a mono 16 bit PCM file with 24kHz or 22.05kHz sampling. I want to turn these into an 8kHz PCM file for input to a custom vocoder. It is possible to use Android's MediaCodec to do this sort of downsampling? If so, how? Below is the code for creating the audio file. Use an UtteranceProgressListener to find when the TTS is completed (passing temporary filename as Utterance ID works well)

```
        File outputDir = mContext.getCacheDir(); // context being the Activity pointer
        File tf = File.createTempFile("sabre", "wav", outputDir);
        HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        mUtteranceId = tf.getPath();
        params.put(KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, mUtteranceId);
        mTts.synthesizeToFile(text, params, mUtteranceId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 24kHz file you need to low pass filter to 4kHz and then take every 3rd sample to get 8kHz data. A FIR filter will be good enough. http://t-filter.engineerjs.com/ will get you started on generating the coefficients for a suitable FIR filter and also provides some simple c++ code. You can work in java shorts for the samples, accumulating into a java int.

To read the wav file samples, either use the Android MediaExtractor or use the java wav file class here http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html. You can use this to write out the resampled wav file.

If you have a more difficult conversion e.g. from 22.05kHz then try the java SSRC here https://github.com/hutm/JSSRC (quite slow though, even in 'fast' mode).